# Generating random colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the code below, the string 'rgb' means what? I don't understand why it's necessary.

```
function randomColors() {
    var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var colors = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
    return colors;
    }
```

Comment: why can't you concat red + green + blue?

Comment: Please try a web search before asking. Basic research is expected on your part .... a simple search for *"rgb color"* brings up lots of results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the syntax of a CSS color:

```
.someClass { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Look like your function is made to return a css color declaration.